# Remap right click key to Fn?

Tags: remapping

my laptop has a dedicated right click key and I was wondering if that could be remapped to a Fn key.

I've tried searching for an answer. I actually found the way to remap the AltGr button to Ctrl. I guess I would just need the labels for these keys to enter it into Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the gear in the upper right. Select System Settings. Select Keyboard and then the Shortcuts tab. Proceed with remapping as desired.